# How to create an api-gateway stage in terraform with no methods in the file

Tags: terraform, api-gateway

I have a main.tf file with my rest-api and all my modules defined within it. All my methods are defined in sub-folders within the main api-gateway folder, so my main.tf file has no methods in it.

I'm trying to create a stage within my api-gateway, but the only documentation I can find uses the deployment object, which requires the "depends_on" field that must reference an integration. The integration in turn must reference a method. But as I said above, I have no methods in this file to reference.

Is there a way for me to create a stage with this configuration?

Comment: How are you running all the terraform file from the subfolders? Are they modules in main.tf?